# How to make and access global variables in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, global-variables, coordinates

I have dropped a pin on a map through a search bar and I retrieve its coordinates, saving them in myLatitude and myLongitude doubles.
This is done in the following snippets of code:

class1.h

```
@interface Location : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) double myLatitude;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) double myLongitude;
```

class1.m

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
 {
[self.mySearch resignFirstResponder];

//geoloc
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:self.mySearch.text completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
{

    //mark location and center
    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D newLocation = [placemark.location coordinate];
    region.center = [(CLCircularRegion *)placemark.region center];

    //drop pin
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
    [annotation setCoordinate:newLocation];
    [annotation setTitle:self.mySearch.text];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];


    //scroll to search result
    MKMapRect mr = [self.mapView visibleMapRect];
    MKMapPoint pt = MKMapPointForCoordinate([annotation coordinate]);
    mr.origin.x = pt.x - mr.size.width *0.5;
    mr.origin.y = pt.y - mr.size.height *0.25;
    [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:mr animated:YES];

    myLatitude = newLocation.latitude;
    myLongitude = newLocation.longitude;
    NSLog(@"lat: %f, long: %f", myLatitude, myLongitude);

    }];
}
```

Now, I want to use these doubles (myLatitude and myLongitude) in a different class2, in other words, I need these two doubles to be global I guess, how can I make them global and how do I then call them in class2? Any code would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would probably be by using a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

You can create a new singleton class that is then accessed from anywhere in your app. So you might create `CoordinateManager` or something and then use this to handle location coordinates you want to be global.

E.g.
`CoordinateManager.h`

```
@interface CoordinateManager : NSObject

+ (CoordinateManager *)sharedManager;

@property float latitiude;
@property float longitude;

@end
```

and `CoordinateManager.m`

```
@implementation CoordinateManager

@synthesize latitiude;
@synthesize longitude;

static CoordinateManager *manager = nil;

+ (CoordinateManager *)sharedManager
{
    if (manager) {
        return manager;
    }
    else {
        @synchronized(self) {
            if (!manager) {
                manager = [[CoordinateManager alloc] init];
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Then you would set the properties like:

`[[CoordinateManager sharedManager] setLatitude:1.067594];`

This can then be accessed from anywhere in your app as long as you import `CoordinateManager.h`.

Comment: Okay so I've set  [[CoordinateManager sharedManager] setLatitiude:newLocation.latitude];  in my searchBar method. 
How can I access this from anywhere else?

Comment: Do not create a singleton for this use case. Just pass an instance of the `Location` object to `class2`.

Comment: @rmaddy That's what I tried at first, I defined my coordinates outside all methods so I could access them, and then created a Location *object = [Location alloc]; in the second class but then object.latitude would give me nothing back.

Comment: That's the problem. Don't create a `Location` object in the 2nd class. Create the `Location` object where you get the coordinates and then pass that specific `Location` object to the 2nd class.

Comment: @rmaddy is it not easier to use a singleton as a global 'storage' for this and then use it anywhere in your app rather than passing around variables? Added to which you can add functionality to the singleton as you develop the app that can come in useful. @dave you would `#import "CoordinateManager.h"` in class2 and then call `float lat = [[CoordinateManager sharedManager] latitude];`

Comment: @RASS Yes, a singleton can be easier but it tends to get overused. What happens when the code actually needs two instances? Don't push global variables and singletons into use when they aren't appropriate. To be honest, the OP hasn't really provided enough details to be sure what the correct approach is. But my feeling is that a singleton is the wrong approach here.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you for the advice. I agree it is very easy to suddenly have too many singletons in your project. Is it simply good design to not have too many or are there performance issues? I know `@synchronized` isn't very efficient, hence why I've designed my singleton to only call it once in it's lifecycle. @dave you can set my answer as the accepted one if you like it (good for me).